# BigQuery: Get row + information about nearest previous row where column x has some value in previous row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have a table with the following schema

```
name       | type
----------------------
id         | STRING
timestamp  | TIMESTAMP
event_type | STRING
some_value | STRING
...
```

I want to get all the events of type `'x'`.  However, I also want an additional parameter for every row returned.  This parameter is a boolean that should be `TRUE` if the nearest event `WHERE event_type='y'` has `some_value='necessary value'`.

For example, assuming the following rows are ordered by timestamp ascending:

```
event_type |  some_value
------------------------
y          | 'true value'
x          | 'not relevant'
y          | 'false value'
x          | 'not relevant 2'
y          | 'true value'
y          | 'false value'
x          | 'not relevant3'
x          | 'not relevant4'
```

I would get the following rows back from my query:

```
event_type |  some_value     | previous_true
-------------------------------------
x          | 'not relevant'  | TRUE
x          | 'not relevant2' | FALSE
x          | 'not relevant3' | FALSE
x          | 'not relevant4' | FALSE
```

I thought a join might do the trick but I can't figure out how that would work.  `LAG` also seemed like a good idea at first, but then I realized that LAG will take the previous row regardless of what it is and I'm not sure how I would use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With BigQuery Standard SQL - try below
>   (*make sure to uncheck `Use Legacy SQL` checkbox under <kbd>Show Options</kbd>*)

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ts, 'y' AS event_type, 'true value' AS some_value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ts, 'x' AS event_type, 'not relevant' AS some_value UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS ts, 'y' AS event_type, 'false value' AS some_value UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS ts, 'x' AS event_type, 'not relevant2' AS some_value UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS ts, 'y' AS event_type, 'true value' AS some_value UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS ts, 'y' AS event_type, 'false value' AS some_value UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS ts, 'x' AS event_type, 'not relevant3' AS some_value UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS ts, 'x' AS event_type, 'not relevant4' AS some_value
)
SELECT 
  event_type, 
  some_value,
  (SELECT some_value = 'true value' FROM YourTable 
    WHERE event_type = 'y' AND ts < a.ts
    ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS previous_true
FROM YourTable AS a
WHERE event_type = 'x'
ORDER BY ts
```

Result is  :

```
event_type  some_value      previous_true    
x           not relevant    true     
x           not relevant2   false    
x           not relevant3   false    
x           not relevant4   false
```

> For BigQuery Legacy SQL - try

```
SELECT
  event_type, some_value, 
  previous_true = 'true value' AS previous_true
FROM (
  SELECT
    ts, event_type, some_value, 
    FIRST_VALUE(some_value) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ts) AS previous_true
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      ts, event_type, some_value, 
      SUM(step) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS grp
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        ts, event_type, some_value, 
        IF(event_type = 'x' , 0, 1) AS step
      FROM 
        (SELECT 1 AS ts, 'y' AS event_type, 'true value' AS some_value),
        (SELECT 2 AS ts, 'x' AS event_type, 'not relevant' AS some_value),
        (SELECT 3 AS ts, 'y' AS event_type, 'false value' AS some_value),
        (SELECT 4 AS ts, 'x' AS event_type, 'not relevant2' AS some_value),
        (SELECT 5 AS ts, 'y' AS event_type, 'true value' AS some_value),
        (SELECT 6 AS ts, 'y' AS event_type, 'false value' AS some_value),
        (SELECT 7 AS ts, 'x' AS event_type, 'not relevant3' AS some_value),
        (SELECT 8 AS ts, 'x' AS event_type, 'not relevant4' AS some_value)
    )
  )
)
WHERE event_type = 'x'
ORDER BY ts
```

Comment: So the legacy worked just fine.  However, I got problems when I tried to use the non-legacy version.  When I substituted `mydataset.table` for `YourTable` I got a `Query is not supported` error.  That's the full extent of the error message I can find.

Comment: if you need this to make work with standard sql but still have problem to resolve by yourself - please submit new question with more details (exact query, etc) - format of comments does not allow to provide effective help in such cases - I will be more than happy to help there

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method: You can use a max scan on "y" to get the id of the nearest y for each "x".  Then use a `join` for the calculation:

```
select t.*,
       (case when some_value = 'necessary value' then 1 else 0 end) as previous_true
from (select t.*,
             max(case when event_type = 'y' then id end) over (order by timestamp) as yid
      from t
     ) t join
     t ty
     on ty.id = t.yid
where t.event_type = 'x';
```

I'm not sure about the exact role of `id` and `timestamp`.  This version assumes that `id` is uniformly increasing with respect to `timestamp`.  Alternatively, you could use `timestamp` -- but it is unclear if that is sufficient for the `join`.